# fortify json injection issue fix

Tags: java, security, spring-security, fortify

We want to deserialize json string by using Gson. I am getting a json from a web service which I am converting it to String and then setting it to Model Object using gson library. On running the code on Fortify security, It is giving me Json injection error on below code with following message :

> The data is written to a JSON stream. In this case the JSON is written
>   by fromJson()

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

Do you have any solution recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, maybe, is about that "jsonString" variable. From where it come from? Do you trust in this source or it came from user input?

Comment: No it comes from a web service. What do you mean "trust" ?

Comment: When you grab some information from user input, you need to verify it. Check the OWASP Principle "Do not trust in user input": https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don%27t_trust_user_input